# Secure, automated _user role creation

Tags: security, couchdb

I'm building a web-app that uses CouchDB as it's backend database.  Once a user creates an account (i.e. they've created a document in the `_user` database), I want to be able to alter their roles to reflect tasks completed.  For example, when the user creates an account, an email is sent so they can verify their email address.  Upon verification, I want to add a `verified` role to the user so that only then they can write to their database (via the app).

The issue I'm running into is that only an admin can alter a user role, so to my knowledge automating this at some point requires admin credentials to be used by the automation process.  I was thinking of emulating the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314815/how-to-ease-couchdb-read-write-restrictions-on-users-database) thread and creating a validation service that receives the email verification and has admin credentials to the CouchDB database.  The issue then becomes how to give this service admin credentials.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107568/how-to-securely-store-my-couchdb-admin-password) thread seems to indicate that the admin credentials can be stored in cleartext in a file accessible to the validation service (but not to anything else).  This feels... dangerous.  But that may just be a combination of my paranoia and lack of deep understanding of security.

So, several questions:

1. Is keeping admin credentials in a cleartext file for the
   validation service ok from a security perspective?
2. Is there another way that I can change a user role without
   needing to store admin credentials?  In other words, is there a way
   to do what
   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107568/how-to-securely-store-my-couchdb-admin-password)
   thread suggests and give only some admin rights (like changing roles)
   without actually using an admin?

If it helps, the web app, couchDB, and validation service are all run in separate Docker containers networked together with `docker-compose` and exposed only through an NGINX reverse proxy also in a separate container.

Also, for various reasons, a solution not involving user role alteration won't work in my case.  I have to be able to track `verified` status in a user role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is safe if the file is stored on the server side and not accessible by the public. (You don't want this file to be served by your NGINX or Apache Server)
2. Not really.

So the way I see it, you need a "registration service" that has the following functions:

- registration (authentication less). Anyone can register
- account confirmation (require some security). Perhaps, it needs a token or something like this

Both these functions use the "admin" account to perform the operations and that's totally safe.